# UWP TextBox focused but unable to type

Tags: input, uwp, textbox, focus, keyboard-events

My UWP app contains multiple textboxes but all of them are have the same problem. After clicking out and inside to the app directly on a textbox it receives the focus as it seems like but not able to type anything. First I need to click somewhere else inside the app and click back to make it work.

[image]

Can you suggest me any idea or solution?

The issue is still persist on a blank new project after adding my style. Both of the default and my style.

Github link: https://github.com/Satukan/TextboxFocusTest/

Comment: Do you mean that when the first time you make the TextBox getting focused, you are not able to type anything? And once you clicked somewhere else and click TextBox again, then it will work correctly, right? It's hard to say where the problem is, could you please share a sample to reproduce this issue here?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I will create a sample later today and try to reproduce it in a new project and share it.

Comment: Get repo link added, can you please check it?

Comment: I could not reproduce the behavior. Here is my step: 1) run the sample. 2) click on the first TextBox, type some words and it works.3) click on the second TextBox, type some words and it works. 4) click on the third TextBox, type some words and it works. 5) click on the fourth TextBox, type some words and it works. 6) Run the sample again and try a different order.  It looks like every TextBox is working correctly when it gets focused for the first time. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Thanks, but the issue come up after a different order, and meanwhile I could narrow it down to the default textboxes. The extra styles are not relevant luckily.
My procedure to reproduce the issue with 2 default textboxes:
1, click on the app
2, click somewhere outside from the app (like desktop) - the app looses focus
3, click back directly to the textbox and try writing (in 80% the textbox is focused but not able to write)
4, click anywhere in the app and back to the textbox - it works 100%

So need to click outside from the app and back again to the textbox directly.

Comment: Although I am not 100% sure that it is bug in the UWP, maybe it is relating with my Windows settings!?

Comment: I could reproduce this now with two native TextBox. I'll report this strange behavior to the team.

Comment: Nice, thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: I have the same issue, is there a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this has been reported to Microsoft several months ago. However this could fix the issue in the meantime umtil a fix is available.

In your MainPage insert.

```
Window.Current.Activated += Current_Activated;

private void Current_Activated(object sender, Windows.UI.Core.WindowActivatedEventArgs e)
{
    yourFrame.Focus(FocusState.Programmatic);
}
```